# Prevent javascript on <a> link within an item that has click event

Tags: javascript, html

For a structure of divs, like so:

```
<div id="magicPopUp">
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link1</a> Other content goes here</div>
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link2</a> Other content goes here</div>
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link3</a> Other content goes here</div>
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link4</a> Other content goes here</div>
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link5</a> Other content goes here</div>
  <div><a href="somewhere">Link6</a> Other content goes here</div>
</div>
```

There is an event bound to the encompassing div magicPopUp that does something (let's say a pop up). When clicking on the "other content" that's when this event should normally trigger.

How do you prevent this event from triggering when clicking directly on a link?

The link works as expected and goes to the page, but the JS is also triggered. Just want to prevent the JS.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

Here's how you can do it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
}
```

Try it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4urqy1fd/1/)